# htmx: hx-swap='outerHtml' gets ignored

Tags: htmx

This button should replace a `<tr>` but somehow "hx-swap" does replace the inner HTML, not the outer HTML:

```
<button hx-get="{url}" hx-target="#offer_{id}" hx-swap="outerHtml" 
        class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Edit</button>
```

See: [hx-swap](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-swap/)

Answer (score 2):

The string is case-sensitive. it works if you write `outerHTML` instead of "outerHtml".